# How do I trigger MyLocation Button click event?

Tags: button, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, eventtrigger

I must find a way to control the my location button for automatically find my location when map is opening. I wanna do it with that way so please don't suggest other ways to find my location. Please focus this way :)

Comment: what did you try so far?